# How to covert json into tree like folder structure in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have Json data as mentioned below, I need to convert the received data into the output example which is mentioned below by using javascript.

```
[
  {
    "modifed": "2018-09-05T14:33:29.816-04:00",
    "Path": "/index/library/abc"
  },
  {
    "modifed": "2018-09-05T14:33:29.867-04:00",
    "Path": "/index/library/abc_form/abc_thankyou"
  },
  {
    "modifed": "2018-09-05T14:33:29.892-04:00",
    "Path": "/index/library/abc_form/abc_thankyou_d"
  },
  {
    "modifed": "2018-09-05T14:33:29.841-04:00",
    "Path": "/index/library/abc_form"
  },
  {
    "modifed": "2018-09-05T14:33:29.788-04:00",
    "Path": "/index/library/index"
  },
  {
    "modifed": "2018-09-05T14:33:29.763-04:00",
    "Path": "/index/library"
  },
  {
    "modifed": "2018-09-05T14:33:29.565-04:00",
    "Path": "/index/contact/contact-thankyou"
  },
  {
    "modifed": "2018-09-05T14:33:29.511-04:00",
    "Path": "/index/contact"
  },
  {
    "Lastmodifed": "2018-09-05T14:33:29.402-04:00",
    "Path": "/index/downloads/downloads-thank-you"
  },
  {
    "Lastmodifed": "2018-09-05T14:33:29.427-04:00",
    "Path": "/index/downloads/downloads-thank-you-abc"
  },
  {
    "Lastmodifed": "2018-09-05T14:33:29.376-04:00",
    "Path": "/index/downloads"
  },
  {
    "Lastmodifed": "2018-09-05T14:33:25.520-04:00",
    "Path": "/index"
  }
]
```

And this is the output that i'm trying/aiming to achieve:

```
path: "index"
modified : "2018-09-05T14:33:25.520-04:00"
|____ path: "library"
      modified : "2018-09-05T14:33:29.763-04:00"
         |____ path: abc 
               modified : "2018-09-05T14:33:29.816-04:00"
         |____ path: index 
               modified : "2018-09-05T14:33:29.788-04:00"
         |____ path: abc_form 
               modified : "2018-09-05T14:33:29.841-04:00"
                |___ path: abc_thankyou 
                     modified : "2018-09-05T14:33:29.867-04:00"
                |___ path: abc_thankyou_d 
                     modified : "2018-09-05T14:33:29.892-04:00"
|____ path: "contact"
      modified : "2018-09-05T14:33:29.511-04:00"

         |____ path: contact-thankyou 
               modified : "2018-09-05T14:33:29.565-04:00"
|____ path: "downloads"
      modified : "2018-09-05T14:33:29.376-04:00"

         |____ path: downloads-thank-you 
               modified : "2018-09-05T14:33:29.402-04:00"

         |____ path: downloads-thank-you-abc 
               modified : "2018-09-05T14:33:29.427-04:00"
```

If some one can help me to write a logic in javascipt it will be a great help. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It would be nice if you would try it yourself first, then post your a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so someone can have a look and show you what you have done wrong.

Comment: At first, sort the array of objects by `Path` property (if the array is a flattened folder tree structure there should not be doubles). Then iterate through the array recursively, keep book on the path level (e.g. count slashes), and when ever the level changes, change the parent array/create a new parent accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following code. It first creates a nested structure where the folder names are also keys in the parent object. A node may be created even before the `modified` date is encountered in the source structure. `reduce` is used to walk through the folders of a single path, deepening the object structure.

This creates a structure like this:

```
{
  "folders": {
    "index": {
      "path": "index",
      "modified": "2018-09-05T14:33:25.520-04:00",
      "folders": {
        "library": {
          "path": "library",
          "modified": "2018-09-05T14:33:29.763-04:00",
          "folders": {
            "abc": {
              "path": "abc",
              "modified": "2018-09-05T14:33:29.816-04:00"
            },
            "abc_form": {
              "path": "abc_form",
              "modified": "2018-09-05T14:33:29.841-04:00",
              "folders": {
                "abc_thankyou": {
                  "path": "abc_thankyou",
                  "modified": "2018-09-05T14:33:29.867-04:00"
                },
                "abc_thankyou_d": {
                  "path": "abc_thankyou_d",
                  "modified": "2018-09-05T14:33:29.892-04:00"
                }
              }
            },
            "index": {
              "path": "index",
              "modified": "2018-09-05T14:33:29.788-04:00"
            }
          }
        },
        "contact": {
          "path": "contact",
          "modified": "2018-09-05T14:33:29.511-04:00",
          "folders": {
            "contact-thankyou": {
              "path": "contact-thankyou",
              "modified": "2018-09-05T14:33:29.565-04:00"
            }
          }
        },
        "downloads": {
          "path": "downloads",
          "modified": "2018-09-05T14:33:29.376-04:00",
          "folders": {
            "downloads-thank-you": {
              "path": "downloads-thank-you",
              "modified": "2018-09-05T14:33:29.402-04:00"
            },
            "downloads-thank-you-abc": {
              "path": "downloads-thank-you-abc",
              "modified": "2018-09-05T14:33:29.427-04:00"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Depending on your needs, you may want to replace the object `folders` with an array.

Note that your input has two versions of the `modified` date: `Lastmodifed` and `modifed` -- both with the spelling mistake. I have assumed that your data is just like that:

```js
function toTree(files) {
    const root = {};
    // Create structure where folder name is also a key in parent object
    for (const {Path, Lastmodifed, modifed} of files) {
        Path.match(/[^\/]+/g).reduce((acc, folder) => {
            if (!acc.folders) acc.folders = {};
            return acc.folders[folder] || (acc.folders[folder] = { path: folder, modified: null }); 
        }, root).modified = Lastmodifed || modifed;
    }
    // Optional: replace folders object by folders array, recursively
    (function recurse(node) {
        if (!node.folders) return;
        node.folders = Object.values(node.folders);
        node.folders.forEach(recurse);
    })(root);
    return root;
}

const files = [{"modifed": "2018-09-05T14:33:29.816-04:00","Path": "/index/library/abc"},{"modifed": "2018-09-05T14:33:29.867-04:00","Path": "/index/library/abc_form/abc_thankyou"},{"modifed": "2018-09-05T14:33:29.892-04:00","Path": "/index/library/abc_form/abc_thankyou_d"},{"modifed": "2018-09-05T14:33:29.841-04:00","Path": "/index/library/abc_form"},{"modifed": "2018-09-05T14:33:29.788-04:00","Path": "/index/library/index"},{"modifed": "2018-09-05T14:33:29.763-04:00","Path": "/index/library"},{"modifed": "2018-09-05T14:33:29.565-04:00","Path": "/index/contact/contact-thankyou"},{"modifed": "2018-09-05T14:33:29.511-04:00","Path": "/index/contact"},{"Lastmodifed": "2018-09-05T14:33:29.402-04:00","Path": "/index/downloads/downloads-thank-you"},{"Lastmodifed": "2018-09-05T14:33:29.427-04:00","Path": "/index/downloads/downloads-thank-you-abc"},{"Lastmodifed": "2018-09-05T14:33:29.376-04:00","Path": "/index/downloads"},{"Lastmodifed": "2018-09-05T14:33:25.520-04:00","Path": "/index"}];
console.log(toTree(files));
```